# How to simulate ARIMA with drift(using r)

Tags: r, time-series, self-study

I want to know how to simulate arima if there is drift.

I have google it, and i search this text http://mgmt.iisc.ernet.in/CM/MG226/Handouts/Simulations.pdf but i dont understand

For instance , if i want to simulate ARIMA(1,1,1),for n=100

if there is no drift,the code should be:x=arima.sim(n=100,list(ar=0.1,ma=0.2,order=c(1,1,1))

However, what is the code should be if there is drift?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add a linear function to the ARIMA process:

```
b <- 0.5
x <- 1:101 * b + arima.sim(n=100,list(ar=0.1,ma=0.2,order=c(1,1,1)))
plot(x)
```

Here `b` is the drift coefficient.